# Can one take away hotel slippers?

Tags: hotels, etiquette

Sometimes in hotels one finds slippers in their room, in addition to toiletries and towels. Is one allowed to take them away, or are they supposed to stay in the room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [nomadwallet.com](http://www.nomadwallet.com/33-free-hotel-items-take-home/), it's ambiguous:

> Slippers tends to get left behind, although hotels generally want you to take them home. If you don’t, they’re going to the trash after you leave.
>
> However, there are exceptions to the rule; some hotels reuse their (usually nicer) slippers.

Personally, I think this site is quite liberal about freebies. I don't take slippers.
I don't know whether most hotels actually trash them after you leave.